# PHP Filter Input Escape Output

Tags: php

Will it be better if i add to mysql_real_escape_string also addslashes like that:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(trim(addslashes($_POST['username'])));
```

And is there any need in this in password var:

```
$password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['password'])));
```

Also i read some topics about safe retrieving data from db...
it says that it would be better to retrieve data like that:

```
htmlentities(stripslashes($v))
```

Is it really necessary for safety?

Comment: Note that mysql_real_escape_string itself does not make anything "safe". It works only with surrounding quotes. When you don't/can't add quotes - mysql_real_escape_string wouldn't any help.

Comment: use prepared statements when inserting data to db. much easier, cleaner, and hack-proof. use htmlentitles when you want to retrieve and display data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- No, don't use addslashes. It does not make the string more secure or better in any way, but adds complexity.
- Escape the string you want to store in the database. So instead of md5(mysql_real_escape_string($password)), do mysql_real_escape_string(md5($password)).
- Think about allowing spaces at the start and end of passwords, thus not trimming them.
- Use a **salt** when storing a password, for securities sake.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the addslashes, that's what `mysql_real_escape_string()` is for!

No need to escape password really either if it's going to be hashed. Though don't use MD5, wait, I'm not opening up that can of worms.

Comment: yeah, i never used addslashes however i saw some tut showing such an example...
why not using md5?

Comment: @Sjoerd, @cthulhu: to be honest, I've heard lots of people saying that md5 is not good because of the collision problems. I don't think that's really the problem for your average website. I would be more worried about MD5 databases like http://www.md5decrypter.co.uk/

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `addslashes` if you use `mysql_real_escape_string`

Also, no need to strip the slashes when retrieving data from the DB if you sanitised the input before entering it in the DB.

Personally I use [HTML purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to sanitise the input.

md5 is probably not the best solution either, use something like sha-128

Answer (score -1):

Is it really necessary for safety?

-Yes.

You sanitize the data on the way into the database (with mysql_real_escape_string) to prevent accidental data corruption, or intentional sql-injection.

You escape the data on the way out (with htmlentities) to prevent cross site scripting (xss).

Both are very different, and very important.

Comment: "Is it really necessary for safety?" i asked only about htmlentities(...
mysql_real_escape_string for sure needed :)
thanks